# Why does echoing $? vary differently when running in this script?

Tags: ssh

I have the following in my script:

```
connectionTest=$(sshpass -p "${pass}" ssh -q -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "${remoteUser}"@"${IP}" "echo quit | netcat -w 5 local.server.local ${telnetPort}; echo $?")
```

When I take the command out and run it manually on the machine, I get the exit code I'm expecting. However, whenever the script runs, the resulting exit code is *always* 0.

Why would the exit code always return as 0?

Comment: Without you sharing the script we may only guess.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro no... it's the `"$x"` vs `'$x'` confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting an unexpected return status is the way you have quoted your command for the remote host.

Consider and contrast these two statements:

```
a=apple; ssh remotehost "a=banana; echo $a"
a=apple; ssh remotehost 'a=banana; echo $a'
```

In the first case, the `"... $a"` is evaluated *before* the `ssh` command is run, leading to this effective situation:

```
ssh remotehost "a=banana; echo apple"
```

In the second case, the `'... $a'` is passed *as a literal* to the remote host for execution, leading to this effective situation:

```
ssh remotehost 'a=banana; echo $a'
```

This is exactly what is happening with your `$?`. Because you have enclosed it with double-quotes, it's evaluated before the command is run. Its value of zero is from your previous command, so what you are *effectively* running is something like this:

```
connectionTest=$(sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh ... "REMOTEUSER@REMOTEIP "echo quit | netcat ... ; echo 0")
```

What you need is to use single quotes to have the local shell treat it as a literal, like this:

```
connectionTest=$(sshpass -p "${pass}" ssh ... "${remoteUser}@${IP}" "echo quit | netcat -w 5 local.server.local ${telnetPort}; "'echo $?')
```

Notice that a string of two parts such as `"hello"'world'` is concatenated to be a single value `helloworld`. The first part was subject to variable evaluation; the second part was not.

Comment: Interesting. I understood that the single quotes would make it a literal, meaning the variable `$?` wouldn't be expanded to it's value, rather it would be echoed out literally as $?. How does this situation differ from say simply `ls && echo "Return code is: "'$?'` which (for me) returns literally $? in the output.

Comment: Forgot to say thank you for the in depth response. I very much appreciate it.

Comment: Oh. I get it now. Local shell sees the `$?` as literal, but the remote shell sees it as the variable. Sweet!